# Issue with the $_SESSION is jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session, jquery-plugins

I have a variable on PHP : `$_SESSION["logCode"]` (the value is set and the session is started) but I can't access it in jQuery using the `jquery.session.js` plugin and the following method : `$.session.get('logCode')` (it gives me undefined). Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how can I fix it **?**

**ps:** I can get the value with php but I need it in JS (jQuery)

*Thank you*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin can't access php session variables (no plugin can, that would be a serious security flaw). You'll have to pass them to javascript from PHP.

```
var myVar = '<?php echo $_SESSION["foobar"]; ?>';
```

Comment: Oh ! I see what you did there ! lol You gave me an idea even know it's gonna be a headache to execute since I have the code that uses the session.get in a separate .js file ! But thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could also store it in a relevant element: `<div data-foobar="<?php echo $_SESSION["foobar"]; ?>"></div>`

Comment: no I already managed to putt it in my nav bar php file that I include every where a member can access so I should be covered thanks god I had that file :) but thanks any way and please leave that comment I might need that method one day.. Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

js won't have access to the php session store. the only way you can get at this is to exposed it on your page with php by injecting the js on your page ... so in php that would be

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo " var logCode = '".addslashes($_SESSION["logCode"])."';";
echo "</script>";
```

or if you want to wholesale get everything from the session you could do this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo " var sessionData = ".json_encode($_SESSION).";";
echo "</script>";
```

but likely the second method might publish more information then you really want.

Answer (score 1):

When you set session variable with php then that variable is stored on the server and it can only be access by php not jquery. JQuery variables are stored in clients computer and can only be accessed by jquery.

You can access session variable from client computer by jquery using AJAX.